# How to lower case a string in Typescript?

Tags: javascript

I am comparing two strings and I want to lower case a string before comparing. How can I do this? 
This is my code:

```
 this.products = response.responseData.sort(function(a,b){

                     if(a.product.productName < b.product.productName){
                         return -1;
                     }
                     if(a.product.productName > b.product.productName){
                         return 1;
                     }
                     return 0;
                 });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to compare two string regardless of lowercase and uppercase using angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068074/how-to-compare-two-string-regardless-of-lowercase-and-uppercase-using-angular-js)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just use the:

```
.toLowerCase()
```

method.

In your case:

```js
if(a.product.productName.toLowerCase() < b.product.productName.toLowerCase()){
                         return -1;
                     }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Javascript's .toLowerCase().

```
this.products = response.responseData.sort(function(a,b){

                 if(a.product.productName.toLowerCase() < b.product.productName.toLowerCase()){
                     return -1;
                 }
                 if(a.product.productName.toLowerCase() > b.product.productName.toLowerCase()){
                     return 1;
                 }
                 return 0;
             });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use new string case operators which are available in **TypeScript 4.1.0**

Please see example:

```js
type LowerCase<T extends string> = `${lowercase T}`;
const lower = <T extends string>(str: T) => str.toLowerCase() as LowerCase<T>;
const result = lower('UP'); // 'up'
```

For more information see [this PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is toLowerCase().
In this, for numbers, special characters will not be converted to lowercase, it is as it is.